# Creating new column with rows shifted up in MySql

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have following table T1 :

```
ID | time
10 | 1000
10 | 1002
10 | 1003
11 | 1002
11 | 1004
```

Now I want to create a table T2 from T1 in which for each ID, successive time-intervals are shown i.e.

```
ID | time1 | time 2
10 | 1000 | 1002
10 | 1002 | 1003
10 | 1003 | NULL
11 | 1002 | 1004
11 | 1004 | NULL
```

so time2 entry is basically the entry of time1 in next row.
How can I do it in MySql ?

Comment: why is it NULL for 3rd and 5th row?

Comment: Where did `1994` arrive?

Comment: Sorry, it is 1004, I have edited it. And NULL in 3rd row because, for ID 10, there is no next time i.e. no time in next row. Similarly for row 5 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this one:

```
SELECT
ID,
`time` AS time1,
(SELECT MIN(st.`time`) FROM T1 st WHERE st.ID = T1.ID AND st.`time` > T1.`time`) AS time2
FROM T1
```